# Maven GWT dependency

Tags: eclipse, gwt, maven

I'm trying to maven install my projects.
I keep getting this error. I was wondering whether anyone can help me. How to resolve this.

As far as I understood It's trying to compile some (org.codehaus.mojo:gwt-maven-plugin) maven's plugin (jar file) and couldn't find some class in it. Correct me if I'm wrong.

```
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- gwt-maven-plugin:2.1.0-1:compile (default) @ admin-war ---
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Reactor Summary:
[INFO] 
[INFO] ecommerce ......................................... SUCCESS [0.430s]
[INFO] admin ............................................. SUCCESS [2.816s]
[INFO] core .............................................. SUCCESS [0.738s]
[INFO] admin-war ......................................... FAILURE [1.444s]
[INFO] site .............................................. SKIPPED
[INFO] site-war .......................................... SKIPPED
[INFO] test .............................................. SKIPPED
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 5.749s
[INFO] Finished at: Sat Mar 31 17:31:43 IST 2012
[INFO] Final Memory: 18M/260M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:gwt-maven-plugin:2.1.0-1:compile (default) on project admin-war: Execution default of goal org.codehaus.mojo:gwt-maven-plugin:2.1.0-1:compile failed: A required class was missing while executing org.codehaus.mojo:gwt-maven-plugin:2.1.0-1:compile: org/apache/commons/io/IOUtils
[ERROR] -----------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] realm =    plugin>org.codehaus.mojo:gwt-maven-plugin:2.1.0-1
[ERROR] strategy = org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.strategy.SelfFirstStrategy
[ERROR] urls[0] = file:/C:/Users/ravi/.m2/repository/org/codehaus/mojo/gwt-maven-plugin/2.1.0-1/gwt-maven-plugin-2.1.0-1.jar
[ERROR] urls[1] = file:/C:/Users/ravi/.m2/repository/org/apache/maven/reporting/maven-reporting-api/3.0/maven-reporting-api-3.0.jar
[ERROR] urls[2] = file:/C:/Users/ravi/.m2/repository/org/apache/maven/reporting/maven-reporting-impl/2.1/maven-reporting-impl-2.1.jar
[ERROR] urls[3] = file:/C:/Users/ravi/.m2/repository/org/apache/maven/doxia/doxia-core/1.1.2/doxia-core-1.1.2.jar
[ERROR] urls[4] = file:/C:/Users/ravi/.m2/repository/commons-httpclient/commons-httpclient/3.1/commons-httpclient-3.1.jar
[ERROR] urls[5] = file:/C:/Users/ravi/.m2/repository/commons-codec/commons-codec/1.2/commons-codec-1.2.jar
[ERROR] urls[6] = file:/C:/Users/ravi/.m2/repository/commons-validator/commons-validator/1.2.0/commons-validator-1.2.0.jar
[ERROR] urls[7] = file:/C:/Users/ravi/.m2/repository/commons-beanutils/commons-beanutils/1.7.0/commons-beanutils-1.7.0.jar
[ERROR] urls[8] = file:/C:/Users/ravi/.m2/repository/commons-digester/commons-digester/1.6/commons-digester-1.6.jar
[ERROR] urls[9] = file:/C:/Users/ravi/.m2/repository/oro/oro/2.0.8/oro-2.0.8.jar
[ERROR] urls[10] = file:/C:/Users/ravi/.m2/repository/org/apache/maven/doxia/doxia-sink-api/1.0/doxia-sink-api-1.0.jar
[ERROR] urls[11] = file:/C:/Users/ravi/.m2/repository/org/apache/maven/doxia/doxia-site-renderer/1.1.4/doxia-site-renderer-1.1.4.jar
[ERROR] urls[12] = file:/C:/Users/ravi/.m2/repository/org/apache/maven/doxia/doxia-logging-api/1.1.4/doxia-logging-api-1.1.4.jar
[ERROR] urls[13] = file:/C:/Users/ravi/.m2/repository/org/apache/maven/doxia/doxia-decoration-model/1.1.4/doxia-decoration-model-1.1.4.jar
[ERROR] urls[14] = file:/C:/Users/ravi/.m2/repository/org/apache/maven/doxia/doxia-module-xhtml/1.1.4/doxia-module-xhtml-1.1.4.jar
[ERROR] urls[15] = file:/C:/Users/ravi/.m2/repository/org/apache/maven/doxia/doxia-module-fml/1.1.4/doxia-module-fml-1.1.4.jar
[ERROR] urls[16] = file:/C:/Users/ravi/.m2/repository/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-i18n/1.0-beta-7/plexus-i18n-1.0-beta-7.jar
[ERROR] urls[17] = file:/C:/Users/ravi/.m2/repository/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-velocity/1.1.7/plexus-velocity-1.1.7.jar
[ERROR] urls[18] = file:/C:/Users/ravi/.m2/repository/org/apache/velocity/velocity/1.5/velocity-1.5.jar
[ERROR] urls[19] = file:/C:/Users/ravi/.m2/repository/commons-collections/commons-collections/3.2/commons-collections-3.2.jar
[ERROR] urls[20] = file:/C:/Users/ravi/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-core/3.0.5.RELEASE/spring-core-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar
[ERROR] urls[21] = file:/C:/Users/ravi/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-asm/3.0.5.RELEASE/spring-asm-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar
[ERROR] urls[22] = file:/C:/Users/ravi/.m2/repository/commons-logging/commons-logging/1.1.1/commons-logging-1.1.1.jar
[ERROR] urls[23] = file:/C:/Users/ravi/.m2/repository/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-utils/2.0.5/plexus-utils-2.0.5.jar
[ERROR] urls[24] = file:/C:/Users/ravi/.m2/repository/com/thoughtworks/qdox/qdox/1.12/qdox-1.12.jar
[ERROR] urls[25] = file:/C:/Users/ravi/.m2/repository/freemarker/freemarker/2.3.6/freemarker-2.3.6.jar
[ERROR] urls[26] = file:/C:/Users/ravi/.m2/repository/com/google/gwt/gwt-dev/2.1.0/gwt-dev-2.1.0.jar
[ERROR] urls[27] = file:/C:/Users/ravi/.m2/repository/com/google/gwt/gwt-user/2.1.0/gwt-user-2.1.0.jar
[ERROR] urls[28] = file:/C:/Users/ravi/.m2/repository/com/google/gwt/gwt-servlet/2.1.0/gwt-servlet-2.1.0.jar
[ERROR] urls[29] = file:/C:/Users/ravi/.m2/repository/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-archiver/1.0-alpha-9/plexus-archiver-1.0-alpha-9.jar
[ERROR] urls[30] = file:/C:/Users/ravi/.m2/repository/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-io/1.0-alpha-1/plexus-io-1.0-alpha-1.jar
[ERROR] urls[31] = file:/C:/Users/ravi/.m2/repository/org/apache/maven/maven-archiver/2.4.1/maven-archiver-2.4.1.jar
[ERROR] urls[32] = file:/C:/Users/ravi/.m2/repository/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-interpolation/1.13/plexus-interpolation-1.13.jar
[ERROR] urls[33] = file:/C:/Users/ravi/.m2/repository/junit/junit/4.8.1/junit-4.8.1.jar
[ERROR] urls[34] = file:/C:/Users/ravi/.m2/repository/org/apache/maven/surefire/surefire-booter/2.4.3/surefire-booter-2.4.3.jar
[ERROR] urls[35] = file:/C:/Users/ravi/.m2/repository/org/apache/maven/surefire/surefire-api/2.4.3/surefire-api-2.4.3.jar
[ERROR] urls[36] = file:/C:/Users/ravi/.m2/repository/commons-lang/commons-lang/2.5/commons-lang-2.5.jar
[ERROR] urls[37] = file:/C:/Users/ravi/.m2/repository/org/jdom/jdom/1.1/jdom-1.1.jar
[ERROR] urls[38] = file:/C:/Users/ravi/.m2/repository/jaxen/jaxen/1.1.1/jaxen-1.1.1.jar
[ERROR] urls[39] = file:/C:/Users/ravi/.m2/repository/dom4j/dom4j/1.6.1/dom4j-1.6.1.jar
[ERROR] urls[40] = file:/C:/Users/ravi/.m2/repository/jdom/jdom/1.0/jdom-1.0.jar
[ERROR] urls[41] = file:/C:/Users/ravi/.m2/repository/xml-apis/xml-apis/1.3.02/xml-apis-1.3.02.jar
[ERROR] urls[42] = file:/C:/Users/ravi/.m2/repository/xom/xom/1.0/xom-1.0.jar
[ERROR] urls[43] = file:/C:/Users/ravi/.m2/repository/xerces/xmlParserAPIs/2.6.2/xmlParserAPIs-2.6.2.jar
[ERROR] urls[44] = file:/C:/Users/ravi/.m2/repository/xalan/xalan/2.6.0/xalan-2.6.0.jar
[ERROR] urls[45] = file:/C:/Users/ravi/.m2/repository/com/ibm/icu/icu4j/2.6.1/icu4j-2.6.1.jar
[ERROR] urls[46] = file:/C:/Users/ravi/.m2/repository/org/apache/bcel/bcel/5.2/bcel-5.2.jar
[ERROR] urls[47] = file:/C:/Users/ravi/.m2/repository/jakarta-regexp/jakarta-regexp/1.4/jakarta-regexp-1.4.jar
[ERROR] urls[48] = file:/C:/Users/ravi/.m2/repository/xerces/xercesImpl/2.9.1/xercesImpl-2.9.1.jar
[ERROR] urls[49] = file:/C:/Users/ravi/.m2/repository/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-compiler-api/1.5.3/plexus-compiler-api-1.5.3.jar
[ERROR] urls[50] = file:/C:/Users/ravi/.m2/repository/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-compiler-javac/1.5.3/plexus-compiler-javac-1.5.3.jar
[ERROR] Number of foreign imports: 1
[ERROR] import: Entry[import  from realm ClassRealm[maven.api, parent: null]]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] -----------------------------------------------------: org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/PluginContainerException
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] After correcting the problems, you can resume the build with the command
[ERROR]   mvn <goals> -rf :admin-war
```

Comment: Which Maven version are you using? Furthermore the gwt-plugin seemed to be a little bit outdated (2.4 is the current version).

Comment: I'm quite new to eclipse. And I updated my maven in Eclipse Marketplace. So I assume it be in its newest version. This eclipse was shared with me by someone. Hence I don't know anything about gwt-plugin. But please let me know how i can update my gwt-plugin.

Comment: First make a call of mvn clean package on command line not inside eclipse...

Comment: Consider posting your `pom.xml` file - and if you are using a recent version of GWT, also use a more recent version of the gwt-maven-plugin (2.4.0 is the latest version of each).

Answer (score 1):

Maven cannot find class org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils. This is included in the GWT Dev package.
Consider adding this to your pom:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.google.gwt</groupId>
    <artifactId>gwt-dev</artifactId>
    <version>${gwtVersion}</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

The build will give you some warning about including the gwt-dev in your dependencies, but I've never had any problem with that....